# Github commit message when deploying to aws beanstalk in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-web-services, jenkins-plugins, github

As part of our CI setup I am using AWS Beanstalk
deployment plugin to deploy my application through Jenkins.

The issue is I am getting git commit hash in beanstalk
application versions description.
I want to have the commit message instead.
I was able to output the message in Jenkins console output using the execute shell step.
but for some reason I can't seem to transfer it to beanstalk.
If I'm using eb deploy the description contains the commit message.
I am getting a blank description with `${ENV,var="MESSAGE"}` in beanstalk.

Would appreciate any help on how to have the commit message
in beanstalk application versions.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

Comment: export the COMMITMESSAGE and tick the "inject environment variables" in the first step?

Answer (score 1):

This gives a short commit message

```
git show -s $GIT_COMMIT --format="format:%s"
```

I'd probably put this in the "Excute shell" command box

Hope this helps!